Computing operator norm of convolution on bounded interval
Consider the space $X:=C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ of continuous real functions with inner product such that $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx$.
And consider a continuous function $c$ from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb R$.
Define the convolution of $f\in X$ and $c$ as $(f*c)(x):=\int_0^1f(t)c(x-t)\mathrm dt$.
This is a linear operator from $X$ to itself, and it can be shown to be bounded by Holder's inequality.
By methods above I can get a upper bound of its norm, but how can I get exact value?
Edited in 6.21, 2024: I give more details how I get the upper bound.
Define $T:X\to X,f\mapsto f*c$. For $f\in X$ that $\Vert f\Vert=1$, I have that
\begin{aligned}
\Vert Tf\Vert^2 
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(t)c(x-t)\mathrm dt\right)^2\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_0^1\langle f(t),c(x-t)\rangle_t^2\mathrm dx \\
&\leq\int_0^1
\left(\Vert f\Vert\cdot\Vert c(x-t)\Vert_t\right)^2\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_0^1\Vert c(x-t)\Vert_t^2\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_0^1\left(c(x-t)\right)^2\mathrm dt
\end{aligned}
So $T$ is a bounded operator whose norm's square is not greater than the last integration. How can I get the exact value of $\Vert T\Vert$?

Fix $x,$ $0\le x\le 1.$ Then by the Riesz-Markov theorem we have $$\sup_{\|f\|_\infty \le 1}|(f*c)(x)|=\sup_{\|f\|_\infty \le 1}\left |\int_0^1 f(t)c(x-t)\,dt \right |\\ \underset{\rm R-M }{=}\int_0^1 |c(x-t)|\,dt= \int_{x-1}^x|c(t)|\,dt$$ Hence $$\sup_{\|f\|_\infty\le 1}\|f*c\|_\infty =\sup_{0\le x\le 1}\sup_{\|f\|_\infty \\  \le 1}|(f*c)(x)|\\ =\sup_{0\le x\le 1}\int_{x-1}^x|c(t)|\,dt$$
Therefore the last quantity represents the norm of the convolution operator.
Remark It suffices that $c\in L^1(-1,1).$ Moreover $''\sup''$ can be replaced by $''\max'',$ Since the function $$[-1,1]\ni x\mapsto \int_{x-1}^x|c(t)|\,dt$$ is continuous.

There's a problem that, it's not space with $L^\infty$ norm, it's space with $L^2$ norm, which is a space with inner product! So skills you use here does not hold.

What norm do you apply in $X$ ?. If $L^2$ the proof is even simpler as Riesz-Markov theorem is not used.
